# How to add Remove icon for upload image of top corner

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

[image]

```
  <div *ngFor="let selected of base64textString;let index = index">
      <img [src]="selected.imageString" style="height: 100px; width:100px;">
      <i class="ft-trash-2 danger cursor-pointer" (click)="delete(item)"></i>
    </div>
```

How to add remove the icon for upload image at top right corner. I'm unable to put that properly ..could you please suggest proper alignment of the icon, please?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```css
.div-image{
  position: relative;
}

.div-icon{
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="div-image" *ngFor="let selected of base64textString;let index = index">
      <img [src]="selected.imageString" style="height: 100px; width:100px;">
      <i class="ft-trash-2 danger cursor-pointer div-icon" (click)="delete(item)"></i>
    </div>
```

First of all, you need to set in the parent div, position: relative, because it will determine who div-icon will respect. So, in this form, div-icon will get the div-image position to position itself inside of this div.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this issue by using  Flexbox very easily try this

```css
.div-image{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    
}
.div> i{
    align-self: flex-end;
    font-size:1rem;
}
```

```html
<div
      class="div-image"
      *ngFor="let selected of base64textString;let index = index"
    >
      <i
        class="ft-trash-2 danger cursor-pointer div-icon"
        (click)="delete(item)"
      ></i>
      <img [src]="selected.imageString" style="height: 100px; width: 100px" />
    </div>
```